# Accessing on-screen elements from delegate function in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Suppose that I have a registration screen, and when the user clicks the "Register" button an asynchronous operation takes place, at the end of which a delegate method is invoked. I want the button to be turned off when the user clicks it (that part is easy), and for the button to be re-enabled if the registration fails (server declined the registration). How do I access this button's properties from the delegate function?

Comment: Searching Google. I'm new to Windows Phone development and this is one situation where I couldn't find relevant examples online.

Comment: Did you get as far as disabling the button? Is it just the UI interaction on the result that you need to deal with? What problems are you getting?

Comment: Basically I want to prevent the user to launch another register request while the current one is being processed.I disabled the button, but outside of the delegate (before the register request is actually sent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've declared the Button's name in XAML, in the delegate callback function, I'd do something like (The Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is necessary to execute the code on the UI thread):

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
       MyRegisterButton.IsEnabled = true;
});
```